# 1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 4

Tags: c#, reactjs

I am getting this error in my react app when i call to an api that runs a console app which creates a .json with information. It returns this output "80.0.3987.132", but it appears to have a parsing error. Here is the api call that throws the error:

```
fetch("api/Version/Installed")
  .then(res => res.json() as Promise<Version[]>)
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ version: data });
    console.log(this.state.version);
  });
console.log(this.state.version);
```

Comment: `"80.0.3987.132"` is not valid json. try `res.text()`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks!